# How do you assign a number to a string array in java then print it?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I made a deck and had success with it. However, I'm having a problem assigning numbers from another array and printing it. For example:

```
String array = {"Bob","James,"Katie"}; 
int array= {2,1,3};
```

it should assign the numbers to the string array and print `"James", "Bob", "Katie"`. I don't want to import any library from Java or use pre methods in java library.

```
    String [] deck2=new String [52];
    String[] deck=new String [52];



    String suits[]={"Spades","Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs"};
    String rank[]={"2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","King","Queen","Ace"};

    for(int i=0;i<deck.length;i++){
        deck[i]=rank[i%13]+" "+"of "+suits[i/13];
        deck2[i]=deck[i];
        System.out.println(deck[i]);}

    int[] deck3={28, 38, 31, 50, 43, 34, 25, 33, 17, 22, 12, 4, 5, 18, 40, 11, 27, 15, 3, 7, 41, 8, 36, 16, 51, 21, 13, 24, 30, 52, 44, 46, 35, 37, 19, 45, 10, 1, 39, 9, 26, 48, 47, 32, 29, 20, 49, 23, 6, 14, 42, 2 };
    for(int k=0;k<52;k++){
        for(int j=0;j<52;j++){
            deck3[k]=j;
            System.out.print(deck2[j]);
        }


    }


}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're saying is a bit confusing but it sounds like you populated deck3 with the index values of deck2 in a random order and you want to use those to print out the deck2 values. 


If this is true then what you want is simply to read the int value in deck3 and use that as the index of deck2, as follows:

```
for(int i=0; i<52; i++) {
    System.out.println(deck2[deck3[i]]);
}

or you can read the value first and then use it

for(int i=0; i<52; i++) {
    int randomIndex = deck3[i];
    System.out.println(deck2[randomIndex]);
}
```

Also, address the issue Mr.Adil pointed out in his answer. For example:

Your values in deck3 must go from 0-51 not 1-52 because arrays are 0 based.

Comment: Thanks that really helped out.

Comment: Np, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

`Array` Index starts from zero, so in the array `suits` the `Spades` has the 0 index, then when you want to get this value you could do like this:

```
String name1 = suits[0];
```

If the specified index is greater than array size or < 0, then it can cause `ArrayIndexOfBoundException`  .

Hope this help you to understand how to accessing array elements.